# using macros within a (new) environment

Tags: environments

I'm working on my CV, and am trying to format job/education listings to look something like follows:

> **Company or University (Location)**
>   *Job title or degree received*
>   Some description of what I did there.

I'm putting enough of these in that I'd like to define an environment to handle the formatting so I don't have to hard-code it (and/or have to re-do every single one individually when I change my mind!).  I.e. I'd like to be able to do something like

```
\begin{job}
\institution{Company or University}
\location{Location}
\position{Job title or degree received}
\description{Some description of what I did there.}
\end{job}
```

And have it output the above.  I kind of blindly tried to define new commands for \institution, \location, \position, etc. using e.g.

```
\def\institution#1{\gdef{\@institution}{#1}}
```

and then create a new environment that does the formatting in the "after environment" code, like so:

```
\newenvironment{job}{}{\textbf{\@institution}}
```

I put both of these inside a `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` block, and my document compiles fine with this in the preamble.  But as soon as I try to actually use this environment, e.g. insert

```
\begin{job}
\institution{Someplace I worked}
\end{job}
```

somewhere in the document body, I get an error that says

```
Missing control sequence inserted: <inserted text> 
\inaccessible
```

when it reads the `\institution{Someplace I worked}` line and a second that says

```
Undefined control sequence: <recently read> \@institution
```

when it reads the `\end{job}` line.

So, clearly my naive approach doesn't work - any better ways to go about this?

Comment: `\gdef{\@institution}{#1}` is a syntax error you can not put braces around the command being defined with the primitive def syntax. `\gdef\@institution{#1}}`

Comment: Also, there is no need to define those commands as global. It might be a better idea to define local commands in the "begin" portion of \newenvironment

Comment: Ah!  Thanks, @david-carlisle - the syntax error was the culprit.  It worked once I fixed that.

Comment: @JenniferL Is it OK for you if we close this question since it seems that you have fixed the issue?

Comment: Yes - I was just about to update the question with the solution, but it's fine to close it.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of ideas- one is using a `\newcommand`, and one uses a `\newenvironment`; perhaps you can tweak them as you see fit

[image: screenshot]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

% as a command
\newcommand{\job}[4]{% 1: company, 2: location, 3: title, 4: description
    \noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}l}%
    \bfseries{#1 (#2)}\\
    \itshape{#3}\\
    #4
    \end{tabular}%
}

% or perhaps an environment
\newenvironment{myjob}[3]{% 1: company, 2: location, 3: title
    \noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}%
    \bfseries{#1 (#2)}\\
    \itshape{#3}\\
        }%
    {%
    \end{tabular}%
    }

\begin{document}

\job{Company or University}%
    {Location}%
    {Job title or degree received}%
    {Some description of what I did there.}

\begin{myjob}{Another institution}%
    {Somewhere else}%
    {Another thing}%
    Long description of stuff| could be anything
    \begin{itemize}
        \item discovered
        \item a 
        \item few
        \item important
        \item things
    \end{itemize}
\end{myjob}

\end{document}
```